# Simple query in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to do a RAW Query like this:

```
User.objects.raw("SELECT username FROM app_user WHERE id != {0} AND LOWER(username) LIKE LOWER('%{1}%')".format('1','john'))
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The query works perfectly in SQLite but does not work in MySQL.

Comment: Try `... LIKE LOWER(`%%{1}%%`)"`. If it works I'll give an explanation.

Comment: Do not do that! This is vulnerable for SQL injection...

Comment: Are you saying about putting a `%%`? Isn't one `%` use for formatting and his raw sql already contain a `%`? As far as I know in this scenario, you've to put another `%`. 
And if you're mentioning about his sql then definitely it's vulnerable for sql injection.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the real query is `User.objects.raw("SELECT id,username,first_name,last_name FROM app_user WHERE id != {0} AND LOWER(username) LIKE LOWER('%{1}%') OR LOWER(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE LOWER('%{2}%')".format(str(request.user.pk),q,q))` and you can't do that in Django ORM I think.

Comment: @Jota: you can definitely do that with annotation :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you show me how?

Comment: @Jota: furthermore `raw` itself is not that vulnerable for SQL injection, but formatting the parameters *yourself* is. The `.raw(..)` has tooling for parameters.

Comment: @Jota: see edit.

Answer (score 2):

After you performed the formatting, Django obtains a query like:

```
SELECT username FROM app_user WHERE id != 1 AND LOWER(username) LIKE LOWER('%john%')
```

As you can see this string contains `%j` and `%)`. This is part of another way to format strings in Python that Django will use to *inject* parameters the proper way. It thus looks for extra parameters. But it can not find any.

But regardless what happens, this is *not* a good idea, since such queryes are vulnerable to SQL injection. If later `'John'` is replaced with `'); DROP TABLE app_user  --` (or something similar), then somebody can remove the entire table.

If you want to perform such query, it should look like:

```
User.objects.raw(
    "SELECT username FROM app_user WHERE id != %s AND LOWER(username) LIKE LOWER('%%%s%%')",
    ['1','john']
)
```

Or better: use the Django ORM:

```
User.objects.exclude(id=1).filter(
    username__icontains='john'
).values_list('username', flat=True)
```

Or we can encode the full query like:

```
User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.pk).annotate(
    flname=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).filter(
    Q(username__icontains=q) | Q(flname__icontains=q)
).values_list('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

If you are after the `User` objects, and thus not that much the `id`, `username`, etc. columns itself, the by dropping the `.values_list(..)` you get the `User` objects, not a `QuerySet` of lists.

Comment: shouldn't it be `('%%s%%')` ?

Comment: @sphoenix: no since otherwise it will be seen as `%% s %%`, and thus not do `%s` formatting. With `%%%s%%`, we get `%% %s %%`, and the `%%` is mapped to a literal `%`.